# Dynamic resizing UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8, height

I try to resize the tableViewCells which have more than 1 line in the textLabel. I don't know why but If a new cell appears, the cell is going to be resized. But If I relaunch the app all cells have the default height. I set `cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0` and `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
 but it's not working. I'm using iOS8 and Xcode 6.3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the estimated height:
`tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0`